# In Go app catch enviroment variables of docker container

Tags: docker, go, environment-variables

I want to create an image in docker of a Golang Application. I compiled the application and created the image over it, and it's working as expected.
However, that application needs certains parameters: Database name, user, ip of the database server, and so on...
So, I know that in docker I can send enviroment variables to the container using the flag `-e` so, my question is:

## How can I catch those values in the Golang application?

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv or https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv to get values from the enviroment variables. I prefer to use os.LookupEnv since I get a boolean saying that variable has a value and then I have my own method to have a default value.

```
func getEnv(key string, defaultValue string) string {
    if value, ok := os.LookupEnv(key); ok {
        return value
    }

    return defaultValue
}
```